# change scp default directory in `~/.ssh/config`

Tags: ssh, scp

The `scp` (openssh) command accepts relative paths as `host:path/` which are relative to the home directory on the host. I would like to change location of the default directory.

For example, I would like to create a shortcut pseudo-host in `.ssh/config` along the lines of

```
Host bar
   hostName foo
   ## this directive does not actually exist:
   DefaultDirectory /home/me/some/path/here
```

so that I could write

```
scp some_file bar:baz
```

instead of

```
scp some_file foo:some/path/here/baz
```

Is it possible with openssh?

Answer (score 1):

The "home" directory is defined by the users' home directory defined in the `/etc/passwd` file.  I don't believe any opensshd parameter will override this behavior.  You can change the home-dir of the user... but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Eh I know of course where is $HOME defined. And you're right, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix for this is to create a symbolic link in your own home directory on the remote server to the directory that you want to access:

```
ln -s /your/long/path/here/to/webapp1 ~/webapp1
```

That would allow you to quickly access the folder like so:

```
scp file foo:webapp1/
```

and allow for expansion in the future (more than one remote folder) and it won't break other programs.  I've found this to be helpful on my servers when I have several websites running on the same server and I need to push files to them (I mostly use git for this now).

Answer (score 1):

Another options is of course a small script/function along the lines of (assuming bash here):

```
myscp() {
  scp ${1%%:*}${SCP_DIR:?/tmp}/${1#*:}
}
```